# External API not working on ipad in my ionic 2 hybrid mobile app

Tags: ios, api, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed an hybrid mobile application. In my app i used some external API which are on my server. I don't have mac so i created ios certificates on my ubuntu system using openssl. 
 [i have used this ionic forum solution to build certificates](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-build-app-for-iphone-without-mac/19929/18)

Then i build app on [phonegap website](https://build.phonegap.com/). I got the ipa and apk build. I run apk on my android device and its working perfectly fine.

Then i uploaded my ipa to [diawi.com](https://www.diawi.com/)  which provided me the link to download in my ipad. I downloaded in my ipad and run it app start in my ipad but when i tried to login then its not working, then i tried to signup but i am unable to signup also. so i found that my app unable to hit the external API. 
I don't have mac so i'm unable to debug it. How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled some more and found that API requests i made are not secured which means i used http:// requests but ios for not allowing https request so i changed my request to https:// and its works.

[ionic blog from where i got this information](http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/)

[anouncement which made about https requests](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/)